# ASP.NET (C#) how to transfer a List<string> to HTML select multiple tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, select

I am trying to create a multiple choice select field in my .cshtml file that looks like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="select-multiple" style="width:500px" name="MultipleSelect">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

I have a model that has a `List<string> MultipleSelect` that maps perfectly when i save my model. all the selected values get to the controller and are saved in the database. But when the page reloads the values don't show. I checked with the debuger and the `MultipleSelect` list gets filled with the values before the view gets loaded.

Should I use a diferent type for my `MultipleSelect` value or is this just not the right way to do this?

Comment: Is your model property name is same as the select attribute name `name="MultipleSelect"` also check you getting the list of selected items on page load for `MultipleSelect`

Comment: Use a SelectList instead of a List as the type for Multipleselect.